# c++, how to have a list of more then 1 element

Tags: c++

I want to have a list that holds an integer a string together. I know I need to use "Pair" somewhere but I don't know how?

How I'd "Insert" into the that list that contains pairs?
(i do not need to use maps, I do not want my list contents to be organized alphabetical order.)

Answer (score 1):

```
std::pair<int, std::string> p1(1, "abc");
std::pair<int, std::string> p2(2, "cba");

std::list<std::pair<int, std::string> > myList;
myList.push_back(p1); // Insert first pair
myList.push_back(p2); // Insert second pair (at the end of the list)
```

Use `push_back`, `push_front` to add elements to the rear, front of the list.

Comment: @DarkoAtanackovic Consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use C++11 features to create new pairs "in-place".

```
std::list<std::pair<int, std::string>> myList;
myList.push_back(std::make_pair(1, "abc"));
myList.push_back(std::make_pair(2, "def"));

// or
std::list<std::pair<int, std::string>> myList{{1, "abc"}, {2, "cde"}};
```

Comment: Or `emplace_back`, myList.emplace_back(3, "ghi")